# General solution of differntial equation $(x^2)(y)dx = ( (x^3) + (y^3))dy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried this problem by many ways , i took $dy$ to other side and tried to form bernaulli equation but it is not helping and not giving me proper answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it as
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2\,y}{x^3+y^3}.
$$
It is an equation of homogeneous type. Try the change
$$
y=x\,z.
$$

Comment: Could a guide a little more because i tried this too and assumed $y/x$ = $t$  and then $dy/dx$ = $t$ + $dt/dx$ which took me to t + $x(dt/dx)$ = $t/(1+t^3)$ . Now what ??

Comment: You have now an equation in separated variables.

Comment: Oh! I was so keen to look out for equation of first order and bernoulli's equation that i forgot my basics . Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2ydx = ( x^3 + y^3)dy$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2y}{x^3+y^3}$$

$$y'=\frac{y/x}{1+y^3/x^3}$$
now assume $y=ux$ or $u=\frac{y}{x}$

$$y'=\frac{u}{1+u^3}$$

this is first order homogeneous equation

$$y'=u+x\frac{du}{dx}$$

$$u+x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u}{1+u^3}$$
$$x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u}{1+u^3}-u$$
$$x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u-u-u^4}{1+u^3}$$
$$x\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{u^4}{1+u^3}$$
$$-\frac{1+u^3}{u^4}du=\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$-(1/u^4+1/u)du=\frac{dx}{x}$$

Comment: I am still not getting it , i reached it here too and then assumed $y/x$ = $t$  and then $dy/dx$ = $t$ + $dt/dx$ which took me to t + $x(dt/dx)$ = $t/(1+t^3)$ . Now what ??

Comment: @SethRollins I have added more details

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we have $$x^2ydx=(x^3+y^3)dy$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2y}{x^3+y^3}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{y}{x}}{1+\frac{y^3}{x^3}}$$
Now, let $y=vx\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$
$$v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{v}{1+v^3}$$
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{-v^4}{1+v^3}$$
$$\frac{1+v^3}{v^4}\ dv=-\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{v^{4}}+\frac{1}{v}\right)\ dv=-\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\int\left(\frac{1}{v^{4}}+\frac{1}{v}\right)\ dv=-\int \frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\frac{-1}{3v^3}+\ln|v|=-\ln|x|+C$$
$$\frac{x^3}{3y^3}-\ln\left|\frac{y}{x}\right|=\ln|x|+C_1$$